# Eliminating AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'focus_set' (Python 2.7)

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit, popupwindow

Using Python 2.7, I have built a GUI using Tkinter. On my GUI, I have a button to open an input popup box.  The call to the popup box is:

```
if analysistype == 'Line of sight':
    d = MyDialog(root)
```

and the popup box is constructed as:

```
class MyDialog(tkSimpleDialog.Dialog):
    def body(self, master):
        Label(master, text="Things").grid(row=0, columnspan=2)
        Label(master, text="Thing 1").grid(row=1)
        Label(master, text="Thing 2").grid(row=2)

        self.t1 = Entry(master)
        self.t2 = Entry(master)

        thing1 = self.t1.grid(row=1, column=1)
        thing2 = self.t2.grid(row=2, column=1)

        return thing1, thing2
```

Before entering anything in the popup box, I'm getting an error; full stack trace is as shown (separated into lines, so it's not just a mash of text):

> Exception in Tkinter callback
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\ajpung\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1536, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)
>
> File "directory/ThingFinder.py", line 547, in fetch_data
>       thing1 = MyDialog(root)
>
> File "C:\Users\ajpung\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\lib-tk\tkSimpleDialog.py", line 81, in **init**
>       self.initial_focus.focus_set()
>
> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attributeattribute 'focus_set'

If I comment out the "return thing1, thing2" line, I do not get this error. However, I still need to return the variables from my popup box. Why is this happening?

Comment: May we have the full stack trace?

Comment: Edited to include full stack trace

Comment: @Slayer I'm kinda new to this, so I know that now.  Is there an efficient method of extracting values from input boxes of a popup window, based off of a GUI build in using Tkinter's `grid`?

Comment: Noted -- that doesn't change, however, that I still get the above AttributeError when the popupbox first opens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `body` method is supposed to return the widget that should be given focus. This is why you get the error that you get: tkinter is trying to give focus to what is supposed to be a widget, but is instead a tuple. In your case, you probably want to return `self.t1`

To be able to get the value of the dialog, you need to define the method `apply` which should save the values to `self.result`. You can then query the result when the dialog is dismissed.

```
d = MyDialog(root)
root.wait_window(d.top)
print("the value is %s" % d.result)
```

A more complete example is here: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm

Comment: Perfect -- exactly what I need. I eliminated the `return` command, which eliminated the error.  The 3 lines of code gave me the output I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: @DingoGetter: you shouldn't eliminate the return, fix it. It serves a purpose.

Comment: I got excited. `return` has been added, solutions works great, even after kernel restart! Thank you much.